# Narrowing down class methods, typing without extending or interfaces and expanding for childclasses (EventEmitter)

Tags: node.js, typescript, inheritance, typing, eventemitter

## Desired Effect

- typed events without having to extend every untyped class that extends event emitter

  - extend event emitter
  - extend server
  - extend socket
  - etc
  - it would be nice if I could just "type" a class using an interface.
  - I don't particularly want to use `const typedee = ee as TypedEE<events>` every time I want to type an instance
- the ability to add on events to a child class without having to chain generics

  - after extending event emitter to type it
  - I have another class that extends the event emitter.
  - inorder to support the child class I have to make every class up to the child generic inorder to pass down events
- the ability to combine listeners as generic

  - when passing down listeners, I may have multiple parents that each need to add their own events
  - something like `ChildListeners extends ParentListeners` when going the chain would be nice. Instead of having to loop over the generic class and the parents own listeners
  - I'll give this a shot, I haven't tried extending it yet. Nope, didn't help.
- enforcing a generic can only be of a certain type

  - reject all generics or omit all properties that don't match the type
- using Parameters or Arguments to type the `ee.emit("event", 1)`. This is not working for me

## Old Post

So, I think using event emitters is pretty common whether the person realizes it or not or it goes by a different name. So the general idea is...

```js
interface KeyListener {
  [key: string]: Array<any>
  [key: symbol]: Array<any>
}

interface TypedEmitter<C extends KeyListener = {}> extends EventEmitter {
  on: (
    <T extends keyof C>(
      event: T|symbol, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
  addListener: (
    <T extends keyof C>(
      event: T|symbol, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
  emit: (
    <T extends keyof C>(
      event: T|symbol, ...args: C[T]
    )=>boolean
  )
  off: (
    <T extends keyof C>(
      event: T|symbol, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
  removeListener: (
    <T extends keyof C>(
      event: T|symbol, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
}
```

This compiles no problem. So lets try and use it

```js
interface ExampleListeners extends KeyListener {
  "hello": ["a"]
  "world": ["a"]
}

class ChildEmitter extends EventEmitter implements TypedEmitter<ExampleListeners> {

}
```

> Class 'ChildEmitter' incorrectly implements interface 'TypedEmitter'. Types of property 'on' are incompatible. Type '(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => this' is not assignable to type '(event: T, listener: (...args: ExampleListeners[T]) => void) => this'. Types of parameters 'eventName' and 'event' are incompatible. Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol'. Type 'keyof ExampleListeners' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol'. Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'. Type 'keyof ExampleListeners' is not assignable to type 'symbol'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.

I'm a bit lost. It looks like it should work fine. Then I realized that I may have to implement each of these functions. In addition, I can't use a generic abstract class because I have to type sockets and servers which themselves need to be uniquely types. Which means every single object that extends a parent of eventemitter needs to be it's own generic and extend or implement my event emitter. What I'd rather do is something like

```js
class NarrowedEmitter extends EventEmitter as TypedEmitter<ExampleListeners> {

}

class NarrowedSocket extends Socket as TypedEmitter<SocketEvents> {

}

class NarrowedServer extends Server as TypedEmitter<ServerEvents> {

}
```

This way I don't have to reimplement all the functions. It just narrows everything down. In addition, because I'm extending classes and sometimes creating additional events I then need to be able to extend those events

```js
interface ExtraListeners {
  "I'm unique": [boolean, number, string]
}

class ExpandedEmitter
extends ExampleListeners
as TypedEmitter<ExampleListeners & ExtraListeners> {

}
```

Since they all extend event emitter, this seems reasonable. Overall I'm pleased with typescript but eventemitters have been a real pain to type properly. I've successfully typed some in a .d.ts definition file but then I wanted to expand it and it was not playing nice. After reviewing my code, I found it was an issue on my end which I have fixed. But nonetheless I want you to notice a pattern

Every childclass that might have a generic child needs to be generic itself. Then I have to pass down the type from the previous to the next. This means I can't just create a class, and let the child class which wants to narrow the events do their business. In addition, the code seems a bit ugly. Instead of...

```js
class Client extends EventEmitter {
    on: (
      <T extends keyof C>(
        event: T, listener: C[T]
      )=>this
    ) & (
      <T extends keyof ClientListeners>(
        event: T, listener: ClientListeners[T]
      )=>this
    )
}
```

I'd rather

```js
class Client<C={}> extends TypedEmitter<ClientListeners & C>{

}

class TypedEmitter<C> extends EventEmitter {
  on: (
    <T extends keyof C>(
      event: T, listener: C[T]
    )=>this
  )
}
```

This way I can keep just extending. But the code doesn't like that

> Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventEmitter'. Type 'WaitableClient' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter'. Types of property 'addListener' are incompatible. Type '<T extends keyof ClientListeners | keyof C>(event: T, listener: (ClientListeners & C)[T]) => this' is not assignable to type '(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => EventEmitter'. Types of parameters 'event' and 'eventName' are incompatible. Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof ClientListeners | keyof C'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof ClientListeners | keyof C'.

Another thing is the Parameters<C[T]> don't seem to get typed properly. I can pass in a string when a number is expected.

If I'm doing something wrong, I'm open to learning

#### Update

```js
interface TypedEmitter<C extends KeyListener = {}> extends EventEmitter {
  on: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
  addListener: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
  emit: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, ...args: C[T]
    )=>boolean
  )
  off: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
  removeListener: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  )
}

class ChildEmitter extends EventEmitter implements TypedEmitter<ExampleListeners> {
}

const c = new ChildEmitter();
```

This compiles fine but....

```js
c.on("swsw", ()=>{
  
})
c.emit("ello", "b");
```

No errors. So the interface isn't doing anything. Maybe I should make it a class

```js
class TypedEmitter<C extends KeyListener = {}> extends EventEmitter {
  on: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  ) = super.on
  addListener: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  ) = super.addListener
  emit: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, ...args: C[T]
    )=>boolean
  ) = super.emit
  off: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  ) = super.off
  removeListener: (
    <T extends keyof Omit<C, number>>(
      event: T, listener: (...args: C[T])=>void
    )=>this
  ) = super.removeListener
}
```

> Type '(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => this' is not assignable to type '<T extends Exclude<keyof C, number>>(event: T, listener: (...args: C[T]) => void) => this'. Types of parameters 'listener' and 'listener' are incompatible. Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible. Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'C[T]'.

I don't know what to do. C[T] is supposed to be Array since it extends KeyListener. I've wasted a bunch of time on this already.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here? The question is very long and hard to follow. Maybe just post how you want it to work and what fails.

Comment: Just added a "Desired Effect" section at the top. Perhaps I should split this up into multiple questions? I am asking a bunch